# How to add kivy.garden.mapview to a screen in a kivy app using screen manager

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am basically trying to add kivy.garden.mapview as a widget to kivy application.

This is how I tried to do it.

I have also added Painter class because if I use Painter as widget it perfectly works but Map class does not.
Also Map if tested as a app with uncommenting return mapview works perfectly fine.

```
from kivy.app import App
# kivy.require("1.10.1")
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.garden.mapview import MapView,MapMarker

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line

xList = [3.2,4]
yList = [2.3,3]

class Map(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        global xList
        global yList
        mapview = MapView(zoom=1, lat=67, lon=42)
        m1 = MapMarker(lat=67, lon=42)
        mapview.add_marker(m1)
        print(xList)
        print(yList)
        for i in range(len(xList)):
            m=MapMarker(lat=xList[i],lon=yList[i])
            mapview.add_marker(m)
        # return mapview


class Painter(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud["line"] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud["line"].points += [touch.x, touch.y]


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


presentation = Builder.load_file("SimpleKivy.kv")


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

and the kivy file is

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = "Map"
        text: "Map"
        font_size: 8
        size_hint:0.05,0.05
        pos_hint: {"right":1,"top":1}
        color: 0,1,0,1

<AnotherScreen>:
    name: "Map"

    FloatLayout:
        Map
        Button:
            color: 0,1,0,1
            font_size: 8
            size_hint: 0.05,0.05
            text: "Graph"
            on_release: app.root.current = "main"
            pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}
```

So how should i do it?

Can i do it without making map a widget?

I need to have a graph so i need to have 2 screens at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually added `MapView` to your `App`. You reference it in your `Map` widget, but never add it to the `App`. One way to do it would be to change `Map` to extend `MapView`.:

```
class Map(MapView):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        global xList
        global yList
        m1 = MapMarker(lat=67, lon=42)
        self.add_marker(m1)
        print(xList)
        print(yList)
        for i in range(len(xList)):
            m=MapMarker(lat=xList[i],lon=yList[i])
            self.add_marker(m)
```

And in your `kv` file, add your initial settings for the `Map`:

```
    Map:
        zoom: 1
        lat: 67
        lon: 42
```

Answer (score 0):

Use POPUP

```
class mappopup(RelativeLayout):
    def get(self):
        x=self.ids.latitude.text
        print(x)
        print(self.ids.longitude.text)
```

---

```
def openmap(self):
        popup = Popup(content=mappopup())
        popup.open()
```

---

```
<mappopup>:
    MapView:
        id: mapview
        lat: 20.9517
        lon: 85.0985
        zoom: 8

        MapMarker:
            lat: mapvie w.lat
            lon: mapview.lon

    Toolbar:
        Label:
            id: latitude
            text: "Longitude: {}".format(mapview.lon)
        Label:
            id: longitude
            text: "Latitude: {}".format(mapview.lat)
        Button:
            text:"OK"
            on_release:root.get()
```